# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," JavaScript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, react-redux, components

Am trying to pass plain javascript code inside of a component to use in index.js render. The code i want to use is a text animation that also has an HTML file and CSS to go along with it.

P.S. I am very new to react

```
    update() {
    let output = "";
    let complete = 0;
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i];
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++;
        output += to;
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar();
          this.queue[i].char = char;
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`;
      } else {
        output += from;
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output;
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve();
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
      this.frame++;
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)];
  }
}
const phrases = ["Welcome,", "To My Website"];
const el = document.querySelector(".text");
const fx = new TextScramble(el);
let counter = 0;
const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
    setTimeout(next, 800);
  });
  counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length;
};
```

**I keep getting the following error.**

```
** Line 61:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  59 |   }
  60 | }
> 61 | const phrases = ["Welcome,", "To My Website"];
     | ^
  62 | 
  63 | const el = document.querySelector(".text");
  64 | const fx = new TextScramble(el);**
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the whole code. With what is here, you have an unmatched } on line 60.

And you should have:

```
function update () {
...
function randomChar () {
...
```